# How to connect to another database in my site more easily?

Tags: php, sql, database

I have many different files for my website and a database I am connected to. When I want to perform some changes in the files or in make some tests, I change the connection it to another database on my localhost, by changing manually in every file.

I imagine that there is an easier method to make this process easier and faster.

Does it really exist?

The information about my localhost database:

```
$DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost';
$DATABASE_USER = 'root';
$DATABASE_PASS = '';
$DATABASE_NAME = 'phplogin';
```

The information about my website database:

```
$DATABASE_HOST = 'sql108.epizy.com';
$DATABASE_USER = 'epiz_26325823';
$DATABASE_PASS = '*******';
$DATABASE_NAME = 'epiz_26325823_phplogin2';
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't store the connection information more than once. Store it in a single `config.php` file, and `require` it in all the files that need it.